# Navigation with tabs not working

Tags: angularjs, tabs, ionic-framework

I am trying to do navigation to tab list after selecting some items from the list.
when I am trying to run my code I am getting  Cannot GET /tab/1337
my selection from the list looks like:

```
<div class="list">
        <a ng-repeat="item in items"
           href="/tab/{{item.queId}}"
           class="item item-thumbnail-left">
```

My app.js looks like

```
 .state('tabs.details', {
    url: "/details/:itemqueId",
    views: {
      'details-tab': {
        templateUrl: "templates/details.html",
         controller: 'FriendDetailCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

   .state('tabs', {
        url: "/tab/:itemqueId",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    });
```

my tabs.html looks like:

```
  <ion-view>
 <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top">


        <!-- Pets Tab -->
        <ion-tab title="Dashboard" icon="icon ion-home" href="#/tab/dash">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>


        <!-- Adopt Tab -->
        <ion-tab title="details" icon="icon ion-heart" href="#/tab/details">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab-details"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>


      </ion-tabs>
       </ion-view>
```

don't know what can be the issue, but hope you will help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line saying `abstract: true` in the `tabs` state definition - abstract states can not get activated. See [ui-router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#abstract-states).

**Update:**

What do you actually expect to happen when hitting `/tab/1337`?

#### Available Tabs

First of all, taking a look at the current state config, you have only a single valid route, since the `tab` state is abstract:

```
/tab/:itemqueId/details/:itemqueId
```

See how `tab.details` it will append it's url the one of `tab`, since it's a nested state of `tabs`. Therefor `/tab/1337` is not a valid route.

What you might be looking for is `/tab/:itemqueId/details` - therefor change your url for `tab.details` to `url: "/details"`

#### Linking

Instead of using the `href` attribute, you should always prefer using the `ng-href` directive when interpolating variables from the angular scope.

In this case I'd even suggest to use `ui-sref` directive from ui-router. This way you can create urls with state definition and also check if your definition is valid.

```
<a ui-sref="tab.details({ itemqueId: item.queId })">
```

In the `tabs.html` your links should look like this to point to an sibling state - given that `tabs.dash` is a valid state similar to `tabs.details`:

```
<!-- Pets Tab -->
<ion-tab title="Dashboard" icon="icon ion-home" ui-sref="^.dash">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>


<!-- Adopt Tab -->
<ion-tab title="details" icon="icon ion-heart" href="^.details">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-details"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

Comment: did that but still getting the same Cannot GET /tab/1337